# UWP C# Updating XAML UI after Polling for Sensor Data

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-iot-core-10

I would like to find out what is the best practice for a scenarios where I send polling message to request for sensor data from client device(s) and update the data details on XAML UI. 
Is is good that once I receive the polled data and update XAML UI immediately or store in buffer and update XAML UI in a `dispatchertimer` of `1 second` interval? Or is there any other better way to go around?
Thanks.

**Update**
Just to be more specific and not getting into code as I thought this would be more about the flow and the UI interactions.
What I needed is to update the client device(s);

1. connectivity status (by updating `image`/`icon` from `assets`)
2. button pressed (by updating `image`/`icon` from assets)
3. sensor readings (display on `textblock` for each device)

It not very fancy graphical intense requirement.

Comment: I'm not a UWP expert, but when I see `XAML` - I think of `MVVM`. Do you have some View Model attached to your View via `DataContext` property?

Comment: You're question is broad; this sounds like a design choice and it's a little bit unclear what you really want. However; without really knowing what you're doing I would just suggest no timer, no buffer and this is me shooting in the dark.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Thanks. I have updated on question above. As my process does not require fancy graphics. I just wanna find out what is the best way to handle it.

Comment: hi @vasily.sib thanks. I don't have `datacontext`. Once i get the data from `socketlistener` I will log it in a `.txt` and at the same time to update the UI.

Comment: @mylim then you should look at [INotifyPropertyChanged interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) and [XAML data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth)